# granim.js does not 'see' images when site is on gh-pages while it's OK when it is locally rendered

Tags: javascript

recently tried to modify one of my webpages with granim.js. I'd like to have
[something like this - third example with forest](https://sarcadass.github.io/granim.js/examples.html)

Unfortunately while it works perfectly during development on my local machine it doesn't work on gh-pages. It throws an error

> Error: Granim: The image source is invalid.

And displays only gradient and not gradient image.I have checked also option with full path from gh-pages:

> https://github.com/Kiszuriwalilibori/portfolio_granim/blob/master/project_images/moon.jpg

and few similar. None of them works, always the same error.
Examples of granim use bot full paths and local paths, so expected that any of tried paths will work. But not. Here is the part of my code responsible for granim:

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
   console.log('page is fully loaded');
   var granimInstance = new Granim({
      element: 'canvas',
      direction: 'top-bottom',
      isPausedWhenNotInView: true,
      image: {
         source: '../project_images/moon.jpg',
         blendingMode: 'multiply'
      },
      states: {
         "default-state": {
            gradients: [
               ['#29323c', '#485563'],
               ['#FF6B6B', '#556270'],
               ['#80d3fe', '#7ea0c4'],
               ['#f0ab51', '#eceba3']
            ],
            transitionSpeed: 7000
         }
      }
   })
});
```

Here's link to not working properly item:

> https://kiszuriwalilibori.github.io/portfolio_granim/#Home

Has anyone an idea what's wrong? As written at the beginning on local machine it renders perfectly. That is not the only image used by that page (the rest renders OK; but the only used by granim).

Comment: Basically solved - works with https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kiszuriwalilibori/portfolio_granim/master/project_images/moon.jpg  so that is not urgent in any sense anymore; however if one knows why it does't work with local path please let me know.